# How to find if file is readable by all?

Tags: perl

How to find if a file is readable by everyone in UNIX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html):

```
$mode = (stat($filename))[2];
printf "Permissions are %04o\n", $mode & 07777;
```

To extract read-for-others bit you can do

```
print "read for everyone" if $mode & 4;    # pick bit 2 from mode
```

Comment: Doesn't quite do the right thing in obscure cases where "others" can read, but "user" or "group" can't.  Also, better to use File::Stat and Fcntl to avoid using hardcoded numbers.

Comment: @mscha Agree that constants are better, however they tell nothing to me until I looked the docs. Per obscure cases, it is still possible to do `$mode & 0444 == 0444`. +1 for your example.

Comment: completely agree that the constants are too cryptic.  I don't know of a better, proper modern Perl solution, though.

Answer (score 9):

The (relatively) modern solution: use [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html), a core module since 5.004, and [Fcntl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl.html), which has always been in Perl 5.  See also [perldoc -f stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;
use Fcntl qw(:mode);

...

my $mode = stat($filename)->mode;
my $allCanRead = ($mode & S_IRUSR)   # User can read
              && ($mode & S_IRGRP)   # Group can read
              && ($mode & S_IROTH);  # Others can read
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function.

Comment: @Tree: If you ever don't know a command, check it using `perldoc -f stat` or checking [stat at perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html)